# Swiper method when swiper finishes loading

Tags: swiper.js

I need to run a function after Swiper finishes loading when the document is ready? Is there a method available for when Swiper finishes loading (applies the first `swiper-slide-active`) after initialisation.

I know there is an `onSlideEnd`, but the very first slide doesn't technically slide when it's first loaded. I want to avoid using `document.ready` because I want to attach the function to the Swiper instance itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version includes onInit, which appears to be what you are looking for.